# parse_ini_file issue with $ symbol

Tags: php, database, connection

i have a **settings.ini.php** file that include my database details.

```
;<?php return; ?>
[SQL]
host = localhost
user = root
password =Gohead123$
dbname = nri_demo
```

And

```
**db.class.php**
private function Connect()
        {
            $this->settings = parse_ini_file("settings.ini.php");
                     echo '<pre>';
                     print_r($this->settings );exit;
            $dsn = 'mysql:dbname='.$this->settings["dbname"].';host='.$this->settings["host"].'';
            try 
            {
                # Read settings from INI file, set UTF8
                $this->pdo = new PDO($dsn, $this->settings["user"], $this->settings["password"], array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));

                # We can now log any exceptions on Fatal error. 
                $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

                # Disable emulation of prepared statements, use REAL prepared statements instead.
                $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

                # Connection succeeded, set the boolean to true.
                $this->bConnected = true;
            }
            catch (PDOException $e) 
            {
                # Write into log
                echo $this->ExceptionLog($e->getMessage());
                die();
            }
        }
```

if i parse configuration (settings.ini.php) file with password nothing display. and if i change password like

```
[SQL]
host = localhost
user = root
password =Gohead123
dbname = nri_demo
```

I get an output like

```
Array
(
    [host] => localhost
    [user] => root
    [password] => Gohead123
    [dbname] => nri_demo
)
```

How can i resolve this issue?please help me.

Comment: working for me, which version of php u are using?

Comment: @Chethan Ameta PHP Version 7.0.15

Comment: try `parse_ini_file($str, false,  INI_SCANNER_RAW)`

Comment: @ChetanAmeta -Thankyew so much..it's working please answer it as commemnt.so i can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with third parameter of [parse_ini_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php) as `INI_SCANNER_RAW`

```
parse_ini_file('settings.ini.php', false, INI_SCANNER_RAW)
```

Output:

```
Array ( [host] => localhost [user] => root [password] => Gohead123$ [dbname] => nri_demo )
```

Answer (score 1):

First - you can move out `.ini` file out of `public_html` directory to make it unreachable or use `.htaccess` on `config` directory. This PHP "hack" is not a good option.

Also, I discovered a note in PHP documentation:

```
Characters ?{}|&~![()^" must not be used anywhere
in the key and have a special meaning in the value.
```

You can try use `INI_SCANNER_RAW` flag, maybe it will help.

*BTW, think about change config to JSON files.*